# Find and close multiple Windows

Tags: c#, window

The code I have below finds one window that starts with a specific "Window Name" and then closes it. However there are multiple windows with the same name open at the same time.  I need to close all of these simultaneously. How do I go about doing this?

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    string toClose = null;

    if (proc.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("untitled"))
    {
        toClose = proc.MainWindowTitle;

        int hwnd = 0;

        //Get a handle for the Application main window
        hwnd = FindWindow(null, toClose);

        //send WM_CLOSE system message
        if (hwnd != 0)
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, IntPtr.Zero);        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? And what kind of "efficient" you are looking for?

Comment: Basically the current code will only close one window thats called "untitled" and will leave the other windows with the same name open, it needs to close them all at once

Comment: Is the form you are running this from untitled and is it the first form close?

Comment: Did not quite understand that, but my application is not called untitled, the other third party applications are.

Comment: You mean other windows belongs to same process or different process?

Comment: All the windows belong to the same process

Comment: @First Second so you trying to close a third party App and you only get one, if it is the main form of that app then you are most likly lossing the handle on the application. Maybe you can find all children of the mainform first and close backwards to the main form.

Comment: Maybe the third party app has some spaces in teh title I would trying trimming the string.

Comment: I think an array might work for "if (proc.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("untitled"))" toClose = proc.MainWindowTitle; but how do I turn this into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Process.GetProcessesByName Method that returns an array of type Process. For example if you have 2 untitled instances open, it returns an array of 2 processes.

See for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName.aspx

Hope this helps:)

Edit:

Enumerate through windows and find the windows by name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        protected delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        protected static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder strText, int maxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        protected static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lp1, string lp2);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        protected static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        protected static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnumWindows(EnumTheWindows, IntPtr.Zero);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

        protected static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size);
                if (sb.ToString().StartsWith("Untitled"))
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my fault should have explained it more clearly initially, this is on the right tracks but the windows don't exactly say "untitled" its like "untitled - abc", "untitled - abg" etc

Comment: Take a look at EnumWindows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Also I need to search it via Window Title. The current code works fine but it only closes one window at a time. I need to turn it into an array which should do the trick but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I think EnumWindows only gives you the top level and no child windows.

Comment: You can try to search the process by process name, and then enumerate the windows and after the enumeration close windows starting with 'Untitled'.

Comment: For child windows you can use EnumChildWindows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @FirstSecond does the code work properly now with the above sample?

Comment: @MartijnvanPut keep getting multiple errors including "EnumTheWindows does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @FirstSecond if you test this in an console application does it work then?

Comment: @MartijnvanPut Yes it does! You're a legend.

Comment: @MartijnvanPut is it possible to use the sb with WM_Close to close all windows at once?

Comment: @FirstSecond Probably not, you must call WM_CLOSE foreach hWnd.

Comment: @MartijnvanPut Basically now that I have all the windows in the sb list how do I execute a function to close them all?

Comment: @FirstSecond Instead of Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); you must calll SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: @MartijnvanPut Can you provide an example? I tried various ways keep getting errors :l

Comment: @FirstSecond I've changed the example above, please try it:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34258/discussion-between-first-second-and-martijn-van-put)